# online tool to manage svn

Tags: svn

I need to apply a [patch](http://code.google.com/p/python-blogger/issues/detail?id=2) to a svn [library](http://code.google.com/p/python-blogger/):

```
$ svn checkout http://python-blogger.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ python-blogger
$ svn export -r10 http://python-blogger.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyblog pyblog
$ patch pyblog/pyblog/__init__.py < pyblog-paiti.patch
```

Can I do it online, using some web tool?

Comment: This question appears to be offtopic because questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I need to update the library as described (i have also written the commands). Can I do it online or without installing any software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without installing Subversion command-line client (or a GUI client). If you have Write access to repository of the project, you can checkout working copy, apply your modifications and commit.

If you want to apply patch to your working copy without committing to the repository -- you can do it even with a notepad. Convenience of this method is doubtful, though. :)